# How can I Open Div in sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three check boxes like chkEnglish,chkGerman,chkFrench.
According to these checkboxes there are three div, and in these div there some textbox and button.
mean every checkbox contain a block of form mean for separate language.

so my query is when user check any checkbox then that for will open.
like if anyone check chkEnglish then english form must open.after that if anyone check chkGerman
then it will come under English.

Mean according to checking checkbox those form must open accordingly......

Comment: post ur code here. or replicate is in fiddle.

Comment: Provide us what have you tried and where you've been stuck. That'll be easier for us to support you.

Comment: +1 VondRitz , Plz post your code  ...

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ericic/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
  <input type="radio" name="a" id="english" value="english"/>English<br/>
  <input type="radio" name="a" id="german" value="german"/>German<br/>
  <input type="radio" name="a" id="french" value="french"/>French

  <div id="englishForm" class="myForm">english</div>
  <div id="germanForm" class="myForm">german</div>
  <div id="frenchForm" class="myForm">french</div>
```

Js

```
$("input[name='a']").change(function(event) {

    var selectedId=$(this).attr('id');
     $('.myForm').hide();
     $("#" + selectedId + "Form").show();
});
```

css

```
.myForm{

  display:none;

}
```

Comment: look at this link http://jsfiddle.net/yZTzm/

Comment: A more DRY form would be to skip the whole `if` thing and just construct the ID based on the checkbox ID: `$("#" + selectedId + "Form").show();`

Comment: @AKX Yes you are right.

Comment: @AKX i have updated my answer.thanks for ur suggesstion..

Answer (score 0):

Just giving a hint how it could be done (I know there are many ways):

```
 var chkName = [......], // Array which holds check boxes id's 
     divName = [......], // Array which holds div elements id's
     prevVisibleDiv;
 for(var i=0; i < chkName.length; i++){
     if(chkName[i].checked){             
         if(prevVisibleDiv){ //condition for the first time.
            //hide prevVisibleDiv
         }
         //show divName[i]
         //store the current visible div inside prevVisibleDiv
         prevVisibleDiv = divName[i];             
     }
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yZTzm/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the following Code :

```
$("input[name='a']").live('click',
function()
{
    var Id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#" +Id+ "Form").show();
});
```